# Laravel 4:: Returning models and its relationship

Tags: php, json, laravel

I would like to return the model and part of its relationship

EX::

User model

```
public function comments() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('comments');
}
```

Comments model

```
public function user() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('user');
}
```

**Can I return all comments and the user's name associated with the comment?**

The desired effect is

```
    $comment = Comments::find($id);
    $comment->user;
    return $comment;
```

This will return the one comment and the associated user full model. I just need the name of the user. And this does not works if I call `Comments::all()`

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for Eloquent's [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)

Assuming your Comments model has a method `user()`:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('User');
}
```

You should be able to do this in your controller:

```
$comments = Comments::with('user')->where('post_id', $post_id);

// Return JSON, as is Laravel's convention when returning 
// Eloquent model directly
return $comments;
```

You can do the opposite as well:

Assuming your User model has a method 'comments()', like so:

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Comment');
}
```

Inside of your controller, you should be able to do the following, assuming your have the $id of the user available:

```
$user = User::with('comments')->find($id);

// Return JSON, as is Laravel's convention when returning 
// Eloquent model directly
return $user;
```