# can i get users associated to every role - laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, user-roles, laravel-8

i have this Laravel (8.0) query ,

```
        Role::query()->where('name', 'like', '%' . $this->search . '%')
        ->orderBy($this->sortField, $this->sortAsc ? 'asc' : 'desc')
        ->paginate($this->perPage);
```

its returning the roles with pagination , nothing fancy

```
    Super user
    Editor
    Ads manager
```

i want to fetch the associated users with every role

something like this

```
        Super user -> admin,root,User1
        Editor -> User1,User2,User3
        Ads manager -> admin,User4
```

Comment: am using  -> https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 4:: Returning models and its relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17508448/laravel-4-returning-models-and-its-relationship)